# 'redux-persist' TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...store.dispatch...')

Tags: react-native, redux-persist

I'm actually trying to set up a redux-persist storage for a react-native app but I always got this error : "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...store.dispatch...')". I tried differents tutorials but none of them worked and i don't understand where it come from.

Here is my ConfigureStore.js :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'


import addBalise from './Reducers/addBalise'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig,addBalise)


export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

My reducer addBalise.js (I know its messy sorry for this...) :

```
import firebase from 'firebase'


const initialState = {
  BaliseSeen: {},
  Medailles: [],
  User: []
}

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "**********",
  authDomain: "************",
  databaseURL: "**************",
  projectId: "*******",
  storageBucket: "*********",
  messagingSenderId: "********",
  appId: "**********",
  measurementId: "********"
};

async function ajoutmedaille() {



}


function addBalise(state = initialState, action) {
  let nextState
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_BALISE':
      var city = action.value.ville
      console.log(city)

      var BaliseSeenIndex = -1;
      console.log()
      if (state.BaliseSeen[city] != undefined /* && state.BaliseSeen[city]  */) {
        BaliseSeenIndex = state.BaliseSeen[city].findIndex(item => item.id === action.value.id)
        console.log(state.BaliseSeen[city].findIndex(item => item.vue === false) != -1)
      } else {
        state.BaliseSeen[city] = []

        BaliseSeenIndex = -1;
      }
      if (BaliseSeenIndex == -1) {

        console.log('Balise ajoutée')
        nextState = {
          ...state,
          BaliseSeen: {
            ...state.BaliseSeen, [city]: [...state.BaliseSeen[city], { id: action.value.id, type: action.value.type, nom: action.value.nom, vue: action.value.vue }]
          }
        }
      }
      else if (state.BaliseSeen[city].findIndex(item => item.vue === false) != -1) {
        return {
          ...state,
          BaliseSeen: {
            ...state.BaliseSeen,
            [city]: state.BaliseSeen[city].map((item) =>
              item.id !== action.value.id
                ? item//not the item we want to edit, return unchanged
                : {//item we are looking for, return changed copy
                  ...item,
                  vue: true,
                }
            ),
          },
        };
      }
      else if (action.value.vue) {
        nextState = {
          ...state,
          BaliseSeen: {
            ...state.BaliseSeen
          }
        }


      }
      if (action.value.vue)
        return addBalise(nextState, { type: "ADD_MEDAILLE", value: { ville: action.value.ville } })
      else
        return nextState || state


    case 'ADD_MEDAILLE':
      console.log('ADD_MEDAILLE')
      var rappel = false;

      nextState = {
        ...state
      }
      return action.value.rappel === true ? addBalise(nextState, { type: "NEW_MEDAILLE", value: { ville: action.value.ville } }) : nextState || state

    case "NEW_MEDAILLE":


      nextState = {
        ...state,
        Medailles: [...state.Medailles, { ville: action.value.ville }]
      }


      return nextState || state

    case 'ADD_USER':
      var nom = action.value.nom
      var mdp = action.value.mdp
      console.log("add user -----------")
      console.log(nom)
      console.log(mdp)

      nextState = {
        ...state,
        User: [nom, mdp]
      }

      return nextState || state

    default:
      return state
  }
}


export default addBalise
```

My App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation';
import Store from './Store/configureStore';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'


export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    let persistor=persistStore(Store)
    return (
      
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Navigation />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Here a complete screenshot of my node.js cmd :
[complete error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHpM7.png)

Thanks if you took the time to help me !

Comment: Please show all error message

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Here is the complete error message :  
``
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...store.dispatch...')

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at AppContainer.js:134)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
``